# Associating enums with template classes at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, types, type-conversion

I have a template class as below:

```
template<typename A> struct TaskInfo{
    typedef A       _A;
    static void bar(A a){blah blah...} };

template <typename TaskInfo> class Task   {
    typedef typename TaskInfo::_A A;
    bar(A a){
        blah blah...
        TaskInfo::bar(a);
    }   
}
```

and I have an object that has a collection of these classes:

```
using TaskInfoX= TaskInfo<int>; //ignore the bar implementation for the time being.
using TaskInfoY= TaskInfo<double>;

class TaskCollection(){ 
    TaskCollection(){
        auto Task1=new Task<TaskInfoX>;
        auto Task2=new Task<TaskInfoY>;
        Register(Task1);
        Register(Task2);
    }
Register(...);
}
```

I want to know if it is possible to define an enum list:

```
enum TaskEnum
{
    Etask1,
    Etask2
};
```

and a function `getTask` such that in my app I can have:

```
int main {
    TaskCollection collection;
    int testInt;
    double testDouble;
    collection.getTask(Etask1)->bar(testInt);
    //collection.getTask(Etask1)->bar(testDouble);  //want compile error.
    collection.getTask(Etask2)->bar(testDouble);
}
```

I know that I can have CRTP or the virtual inheritance equivalent that allows me to pass variadic arguments for bar() but I want to have type checking on the parameters of the bar function at compile time. Is this impossible in C++?

Update: Apologise for the typo. That was meant to be: getTask(task1). basically the outside world doesn't know about the underlying structure of the tasks and only knows them based on their public enum keys. Also note that in general there would be additional tasks potentially reusing the typeInfoX parameter.

Comment: CRTP is all compile time so why are you bothering to use it?

Comment: Something like `collection.getTask<Task1>()->bar(testInt);` might be possible.

Comment: Apologise for the typo. That was meant to be: getTask(task1) basically the outside world doesn't know about the underlying structure of the tasks and only knows them based on their public enum keys.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not sure I understand your question but as I said, I want static type checking for the bar arguments

Comment: @shu The whole point of CRTP based patterns and dispatching is static type checking (aka static polymorphism) done at compile time.

Comment: Oh I see. Can you show me how you would do this? All the examples I have seen have been for void functions taking void and I don't really know how to take in parameters of a type not yet defined in the base class.

Comment: To clarify,  I mean like the editor telling me that bar is going to take in int and not actually when I hit compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always template a concrete class with primitives. So instead of:

```
using TaskInfoX= TaskInfo<int>;
using TaskInfoY= TaskInfo<double>;
```

you can just have

```
template<> class Task<TaskEnum::Task1> : public TaskInfo<int>{}
template<> class Task<TaskEnum::Task2> : public TaskInfo<double>{}
```

and then define a template function:

```
template<TaskEnum taskE>    
Task<taskE>* getTask() {}
```

You will need to derive template class Task from a base class so you can put it in a map, and you should define a map

```
std::map<TaskEnum,TaskBase*>    taskMap;
```

and in getTask you can just do a static cast:

```
static_cast<Task<taskE>* >(taskBasePtr);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to have error if type is not an exact match, you may use the following:

```
template <typename T>
class Task
{
public:
    using type = typename T::type;

    void bar(type a) { T::bar(a); }

    template <typename U>
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<U>, type>::value>
    bar(U&&) = delete;
};
```

Then, with some helpers:

```
template <TaskEnum> struct TaskMap;

template <> struct TaskMap<Etask1> { using type = Task<TaskInfoX>; };
template <> struct TaskMap<Etask2> { using type = Task<TaskInfoY>; };
```

Your collection could be something like:

```
class TaskCollection
{ 
public:
    Task<TaskInfoX> taskX;
    Task<TaskInfoY> taskY;

    template <TaskEnum E>
    typename TaskMap<E>::type&
    getTask();
};

template <>
Task<TaskInfoX>& TaskCollection::getTask<Etask1>() { return taskX; }

template <>
Task<TaskInfoY>& TaskCollection::getTask<Etask2>() { return taskY; }
```

With final usage:

```
collection.getTask<Etask1>().bar(testInt);
collection.getTask<Etask1>().bar(testDouble);//error:call to deleted member function 'bar'
collection.getTask<Etask2>().bar(testDouble);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81bb419849e1849c)

Answer (score 0):

I think [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is what you need:

```
auto my_tuple = std::make_tuple(Task<TaskInfoX>(), Task<TaskInfoY>());
std::get<Task<TaskInfoX>>(my_tuple).bar(12);
// actually, this is not an error because double can be convert to int
std::get<Task<TaskInfoX>>(my_tuple).bar(12.323);
```

Comment: Apologise for the typo. That was meant to be: getTask(task1) basically the outside world doesn't know about the underlying structure of the tasks and only knows them based on their public enum keys.

Comment: Didn't know you could have type access in a tupple. Cool. Guess I could have a similar approach and access the tupple by indices but that would mean I need to maintain my list of tasks as well as the tupple which is inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

Given the way Task1 and Task2 are stored in your TaskCollection class, I cant see an obvious way to implement getTask as a template, but you can overload it.

```
class TaskCollection
{
    //...
    Task<TaskInfoX> GetTask(Task<TaskInfoX> task)
    {
        return Task1;
    }

    Task<TaskInfoY> GetTask(Task<TaskInfoY> task)
    {
        return Task2;
    }
};
```

If your real case works in with double and int then you need to supress the conversion from double to int in order to achieve this compile-time error...

//collection.getTask(Task1)->bar(testDouble);  //want compile error.

one way to do this is to declare but not define a template version of bar in your TaskInfo

```
template<typename A> struct TaskInfo
{   
    static void bar(A a){blah blah...}
    template<typename T> static void bar(T a); // deliberately not defined
    //...
};
```

you still define your existing bar function for the type you do want to handle, but now, in the case that you want to fail, the compiler will try to call the template version of bar (with T as a double) in preference to calling the int version with a conversion from double to int. The resulting error in VS2015 is

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __thiscall C::bar(double)

but if no code tries to call it then it doesn't matter that it is not defined an there is no error.

(It wasn't clear to me what the question was regarding the enum)

Comment: Apologise for the typo. That was meant to be: getTask(task1) and not Task1. basically the outside world doesn't know about the underlying structure of the tasks and only knows them based on their public enum keys. As for my real world example, the tasks basically represent  delegate/signal objects and I would be type defining function pointers of the right type etc. So no, not primitives.

Comment: In that case I'd use template speciailisation on the enum values, but Jarod42 has added an answer that covers that well enough.